# Plone: Full admin rights, but edit bar is missing

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

The user has Site administrator and Manager roles enabled, can access Site Setup, can access folder_contents, can edit items.

But edit-bar is missing in all sections. Only for this user.

Can you give me a hint on how to investigate this?

Comment: Which Plone-vs.? Have you done an upgrade lately? Does creating a new user and granting same perms result in the same error? Any err-msgs in the browser-console? Any errs when running instance in foreground?

Comment: Plone 4.3.10 (4313) is the version. A new diazo theme was installed recently. No, the problem is only for this user. Need to ask and investigate the last 2 questions.

Comment: Do you remember if the edit-bar was visible to this user before installing the theme? If so, the theme is likely the cause, otherwerwise the theme cannot have caused the missing edit-bar.

Comment: You could dig through the page source code, maybe it's just CSS gone haywire. (I assume you've cross-checked with users that are also SAdmin/Mgr, and you've cleaned the browser cache?)

Comment: Thanks for help. Right: the problem was related to the new theme and sure it was a minor css problem. A media query for small screens with display none for edit-bar...

Comment: Please remember that our forum at https://community.plone.org is where most of us hang out

Comment: I like stackoverflow. It gives me points. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related to the new theme and sure it was a minor css problem. A media query for small screens with display none for edit-bar.